# JS: finding index of the nested Array and take the key value out of the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object from osm search. And, the tags are like below.

```
 a: {   
    tg: [
      ["leisure", "stadium"],
      ["name", "AA Stadium"],
      ["key", "game"],
    ]
   }

 b: {   
    tg: [
      ["key", "game"],
    ]
   }

c: {   
    tg: [
      ["name", "GTA"],
      ["key", "game"],
    ]
   }
```

Some do not have the name. Therefore, first, I want to check if `name` exits and then if it exists, returns the index of its array in order to get the name. I can get the name value with the index, but I am stuck at getting index number of the array that contains the name.

How can I get the index of the array that contains `name` value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const a = { tg: [ [ 'leisure', 'stadium'] , [ 'name', 'AA Stadium'] , [ 'key', 'game'] ] } 
    , b = { tg: [ [ 'key', 'game'] ] } 
    , c = { tg: [ [ 'name', 'GTA'] , [ 'key', 'game'] ] } 


let aTG =  Object.fromEntries(a.tg)
  , bTG =  Object.fromEntries(b.tg)
  , cTG =  Object.fromEntries(b.tg)
  
console.log( 'aTG asName ?', Boolean(aTG.name) )
console.log( 'bTG asName ?', Boolean(bTG.name) )
console.log( 'cTG asName ?', Boolean(cTG.name) )

if (!!aTG.name) console.log( 'aTG.key ->', aTG.key )
```